# array view in table format

Tags: php, html

How can I display array in table format

array is

```
        Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [MarketName] => BTC-1ST
                [High] => 9.55E-5
                [Low] => 8.5E-5
                [Volume] => 1557119.52168
                [Last] => 8.75E-5
                [BaseVolume] => 138.34919019
                [TimeStamp] => 2017-09-29T09:03:03.743
                [Bid] => 8.735E-5
                [Ask] => 8.765E-5
                [OpenBuyOrders] => 409
                [OpenSellOrders] => 5994
                [PrevDay] => 8.56E-5
                [Created] => 2017-06-06T01:22:35.727
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [MarketName] => BTC-2GIVE
                [High] => 1.56E-6
                [Low] => 1.45E-6
                [Volume] => 3448220.38871
                [Last] => 1.5E-6
                [BaseVolume] => 5.1828602
                [TimeStamp] => 2017-09-29T08:55:45.413
                [Bid] => 1.49E-6
                [Ask] => 1.5E-6
                [OpenBuyOrders] => 363
                [OpenSellOrders] => 1976
                [PrevDay] => 1.48E-6
                [Created] => 2016-05-16T06:44:15.287
            )
)
```

there not only two array ....i have many number of array ....but hoe can i display it in table...??

i want to display like this 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu3dF.png)

i tried this code

```
<table class="table table-hover">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Buy Orders</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>                                     
                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center"><b>Market</b></td>
                                        <td align="center"><b>High</b></td>
                                    </tr>

                                    <tr>
                                        <td align="center"><?php echo $b[0]['MarketName'];?></td>
                                        <td align="center"><?php echo $b[0]['High'];?></td>
                                    </tr>

                                </tbody>
                            </table>
```

i want to all array view in this format like $result[0],$result[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hu3dF.png),...

Comment: Stackoverflow does not code for you. What have you tried?

Comment: whats the array name

Comment: show some code u tried

Comment: there are 258 array so how can i dynamically display it

Comment: read about loops. [foreach()](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) for instance

Comment: can you give me code for this..?

Comment: add $Arr loop before you print <tr><td> ..... $Arr[i]['Name']

Comment: please send me for loop code for it......

Comment: There are plenty examples on that. We can't give you the code for your case, you have to learn from examples and adopt them to your case. And write here a question when you stuck in specific place etc. so you could get an advice

Answer (score 1):

Learn more about:

for each https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping.asp

arrays https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays.asp

multidimensional arrays https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_arrays_multi.asp

```
<table class="table table-hover">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2" class="text-center">Buy Orders</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>                                     
    <tr>
        <td align="center"><b>Market</b></td>
        <td align="center"><b>High</b></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <?php
        foreach ($result as $k=>$v)
        {
        ?>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $result[$k]['MarketName'];?></td>
        <td align="center"><?php echo $result[$k]['High'];?></td>
        <?php 
        }
        ?>
    </tr>

</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use foreach loop to iterate through your records and show each one in a table row.

created this sample for you from your code

```
$records = [
    [
    "MarketName"     => "BTC-1ST",
    "High"           => "9.55E-5",
    "Low"            => "8.5E-5",
    "Volume"         => "1557119.52168",
    "Last"           => "8.75E-5",
    "BaseVolume"     => "138.34919019",
    "TimeStamp"      => "2017-09-29T09:03:03.743",
    "Bid"            => "8.735E-5",
    "Ask"            => "8.765E-5",
    "OpenBuyOrders"  => "409",
    "OpenSellOrders" => "5994",
    "PrevDay"        => "8.56E-5",
    "Created"        => "2017-06-06T01:22:35.727",
    ],[
    "MarketName"     => "BTC-2GIVE",
    "High"           => "1.56E-6",
    "Low"            => "1.45E-6",
    "Volume"         => "3448220.38871",
    "Last"           => "1.5E-6",
    "BaseVolume"     => "5.1828602",
    "TimeStamp"      => "2017-09-29T08:55:45.413",
    "Bid"            => "1.49E-6",
    "Ask"            => "1.5E-6",
    "OpenBuyOrders"  => "363",
    "OpenSellOrders" => "1976",
    "PrevDay"        => "1.48E-6",
    "Created"        => "2016-05-16T06:44:15.287",
    ],
];

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "
<tr>
    <th>heading</th>
    <th>heading</th>
    <th>heading</th>
    <th>heading</th>
    <th>heading</th>
    <th>heading</th>
    <th>heading</th>
    <th>heading</th>
    <th>heading</th>
    <th>heading</th>
    <th>heading</th>
    <th>heading</th>
    <th>heading</th>
</tr>
";
foreach($records as $value){
echo "
<tr>
    <td>{$value["MarketName"]}</td>
    <td>{$value["High"]}</td>
    <td>{$value["Low"]}</td>
    <td>{$value["Volume"]}</td>
    <td>{$value["Last"]}</td>
    <td>{$value["BaseVolume"]}</td>
    <td>{$value["TimeStamp"]}</td>
    <td>{$value["Bid"]}</td>
    <td>{$value["Ask"]}</td>
    <td>{$value["OpenBuyOrders"]}</td>
    <td>{$value["OpenSellOrders"]}</td>
    <td>{$value["PrevDay"]}</td>
    <td>{$value["Created"]}</td>
</tr>
";
}
echo "</table>";
```

**Example:** https://3v4l.org/Wpqnb